# What I am doing here wrong with memory leak

Tags: reactjs, ajax, typescript, react-native, es6-promise

I have this code which calls an ajx request and set an error if returned 2. It is returning 2; but no error messages showing up and gets to next page (as if it is a success)

```
 isCodeExists(userInput).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
  if (res == 2) console.log("it is 2!!");
  // Any other logic that needs the value of `res` should come here...
  setErrorMessage('Paper Form ID must begin with "HBCD".');
  setHasError(true);
  return false;
});
```

The console says: **react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions, and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
At PaperFormPage**

The full PaperForm Page Code

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import TextboxScannerElement from './TextboxScannerElement';

export default function PaperFormPage(props) {
  const [pageUserInput, setPageUserInput] = useState([]);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.pageData !== undefined) {
      setPageUserInput([...props.pageData]);
    }
  }, [props.pageData]);

  // element = TextboxElement name
  function onUserInput(element, value) {
    setErrorMessage('');
    setHasError(false);

    if (typeof element === 'string') {
      let pageUserInputCopy = [...pageUserInput];
      let index = pageUserInputCopy.findIndex((obj) => obj.key === element);
      let itemCopy = { ...pageUserInputCopy[index] };

      itemCopy['userInput'] = value;
      pageUserInputCopy[index] = itemCopy;

      setPageUserInput(pageUserInputCopy);
    }
  }

  function isCodeExists(userInput) {
    setErrorMessage('');
    setHasError(false);
    let code = encodeURIComponent(userInput);
    const testURL =
      loris.BaseURL +
      '/biosample/ajax/validateScannableCode.php' +
      '?scannable_code=' +
      code;

    return fetch(
      testURL,
      {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        if(responseData==2) {
          return 2;
        }
        else{
          return 1;
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.warn(error));;

  }

  function isValid(userInput) {
    if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(userInput)) {
      setErrorMessage('Cannot contain non-alphanumeric characters.');
      setHasError(true);
      return false;
    }

    if (!/^.{10,}$/.test(userInput)) {
      setErrorMessage('Must be at least 10 characters in length.');
      setHasError(true);
      return false;
    }

    if (!userInput.startsWith('HBCD')) {
      setErrorMessage('Paper Form ID must begin with "HBCD".');
      setHasError(true);
      return false;
    }
    isCodeExists(userInput).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res == 2) console.log("it is 2!!");
      // Any other logic that needs the value of `res` should come here...
      setErrorMessage('Paper Form ID must begin with "HBCD".');
      setHasError(true);
      return false;
    });

    return true;
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    if (isValid(pageUserInput[0].userInput)) {
      props.updatePageData(pageUserInput);
      props.nextStep();
    }
  }

  const form =
    pageUserInput.length === 0 ? null : (
      <TextboxScannerElement
        keyStr={pageUserInput[0].key}
        label={pageUserInput[0].label}
        name={pageUserInput[0].key}
        onUserInput={onUserInput}
        value={pageUserInput[0].userInput}
        errorMessage={errorMessage}
      />
    );

  return (
    <>
      <div className="instructions">
        <strong>Instructions:</strong>
        <p>Scan the Paper Form found in the kit.</p>
      </div>
      <FormElement
        className="FormElement"
        name="form"
        fileUpload={false}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        onUserInput={onUserInput}
      >
        {form}
        <ButtonElement label="Next" onUserInput={onUserInput} />
      </FormElement>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `isValid` function.

This function uses async code but doesn't wait for it.

When the code in `then` happens the component is already unloaded.

```
function isValid(userInput) {
    // ...
    isCodeExists(userInput).then(res => {
      if (res == 2) console.log("it is 2!!");
      setErrorMessage('Paper Form ID must begin with "HBCD".');
      setHasError(true);
      // this return doesn't return from `isValid` it returns from the inline function you just created
      return false;
    });

    // the next line always returns true as you never await from the promise above
    return true;
}
```

To solve the issue mark the function as `async` and use `await.

```
async function isValid(userInput) {
    // ...
    const response = await isCodeExists(userInput)
    if (res == 2) {
      setErrorMessage('Paper Form ID must begin with "HBCD".');
      setHasError(true);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
    if (await isValid(pageUserInput[0].userInput)) {
      props.updatePageData(pageUserInput);
      props.nextStep();
    }
}
```

Also, you named you named your function `isValid` which would suggest that it's not setting anything and just checking if something is valid, but you set the state inside anyway.